# How Fix Android phones running low on internal memory?

Tags: android, performance

> I have use Samsung note and grand please help me.

Comment: the only fix is to uninstall some applications

Comment: You should look at Android enthusiasts: http://android.stackexchange.com/ 
The regular stackoverflow is only for programming related questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Dial *#9900# - This will bring up the following screen - Sysdump
>
> [image]
>
> 2. Hit the 'Delete dumpstate/logcat' button. Hit OK on the confirmation dialog.
> 3. Scroll to the end of the screen and hit 'Exit'
>
> That's it!
>
> I've seen about 800MB freed the first time I used this.
>
> As a next step I'd recommend the 'Clean Master' free app to manage
> your cache, data, moving files to SD card etc